# Tensorflow: Using list of tensors possible with tf.function?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I am trying to build to build simple RNN in tensorflow with eager execution.

Here is my code where I have problem

```
@tf.function
def rnn(self,X):
    outputs=[]
    state=self.state
    for x in X:
        output,state=self.basic_rnn_cell(x,state)
        outputs.append(output)
    return outputs
```

As you can see I want to create list of tensors which I can then feed to optimizer .This code works fine without `tf.function` decoration. With decoration autograph is having hard time with python list. I get error like this

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InaccessibleTensorError: The tensor 'Tensor("while/StatefulPartitionedCall:0", shape=(2, 1), dtype=float32)' cannot be accessed here: it is defined in another function or code block. Use return values, explicit Python locals or TensorFlow collections to access it. Defined in: FuncGraph(name=while_body_51, id=2300683156496); accessed from: FuncGraph(name=rnn, id=2300681517808).
```

I have tried with `tf.concat` but it is having trouble with variable length variable in loop.

Is there any work around to solve this?

Comment: With `@tf.function` you are creating a graph. You can't have a python list and append to it in a graph. Try eager execution by removing `@tf.function`.

Comment: @Peyman I don't want to remove tf.function as I want graph. Do you know any kind of graph compatible list?

Comment: Maybe you can try using a [TensorArray](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/TensorArray) instead of a list.